# sort the values in dictionary using python using alphanumeric values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

```
dict = {'454133': 'PSJ', '420771': 'PSM', '403811': 'PSB', '434330': 'PSG', 
        '329745': 'PSG', '460192': 'PSC', '421534': 'PSA', '398614': 'PSM', 
        '398920': 'PSE', '403962': 'PSP', '331110': 'PSQ', '398436': 'PSP', 
        '306762': 'PSE', '403714': 'PSO', '460145': 'PSC', '398394': 'PST', 
        '451324': 'PSS', '255695': 'PSD', '237330': 'PSC', '398572': 'PSD', 
        '437653': 'PSR', '425822': 'PSI', '311786': 'PSS', '412713': 'PSK', 
        '460184': 'PSA', '328371': 'PSF', '344331': 'PSJ', '367531': 'PSR', 
        '109754': 'PS3', '404903': 'PSK', '402154': 'PSN', '399552': 'PSH', 
        '425861': 'PSL', '446234': 'PSF', '309296': 'PSO', '447616': 'PSH', 
        '151336': 'PSA', '306000': 'PSI', '404370': 'PSL', '103661': 'PS2',
        '439822': 'PSN', '087265': 'PS1', '413635': 'PSB', '265040': 'PSQ', 
        '141005': 'PSB', '111111': 'PS10', '151515': 'PS20'}
```

I would like to sort the dictionary by the values and get the list of the keys in order.
The keys with a value in [A-Z]+ should appear on top and the keys with a value in [A-Z0-9]+ should appear last.

The result should be :

```
['141005', '151336', '237330', '255695', '265040', '306000', '306762', '309296', 
 '311786', '328371', '329745', '331110', '344331', '367531', '398394', '398436', 
 '398572', '398614', '398920', '399552', '402154', '403714', '403811', '403962', 
 '404370', '404903', '412713', '413635', '420771', '421534', '425822', '425861', 
 '434330', '437653', '439822', '446234', '447616', '451324', '454133', '460145', 
 '460184', '460192', '087265', '103661', '109754', '111111', '151515']
```

I have already tried the following, but it always gives the [A-Z0-9]+ keys first and the [A-Z]+ keys last.

```
sorted_dict = sorted(dict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: I'm wondering how you got the "should be" result?

Comment: Since someone is required to say this once every hour or so on SO, and no one's done it yet, I guess it's my turn: don't call your dictionaries `dict` or your lists `list`, etc.  That clobbers the built-in types, and they're handy to have around.  Even if you know better and don't do it in your real code, using those names in examples makes people have to warn you about it, so it saves time if you don't. :^)

Answer (score 4):

```
sorted_dict = sorted(
    dict.iteritems(),
    key=lambda (_,value): tuple((not c.isalpha(), c) for c in value)
)
```

Explanation: The characters are compared by:

1. Whether the character is alphabetic, with alphabetic ones coming first.
2. The default lexicographic comparison

And then to get the final result,

```
map(operator.itemgetter(0), sorted_dict)
```

**But** shouldn't `'421534', '460184', '151336'` (in some order) be first? Those are the keys with `'PSA'` for the value.

EDIT: You are vague on what sorting order you want (e.g. which comes first out of hat comes first out of `'AB12C'` and `'AB2C'`?).

However, this is another possibility:

```
def parts(s):
    parts = []
    for part in re.split('(?=\\d)', s)
        try:
            parts.append(int(part))
        except ValueError:
            parts.append(part)

sorted_dict = sorted(dict.iteritmes(), key=lambda (_,value): parts(value)))
```

This would put `'PS3'` before `'PS20'` and `'AB2C'` before `'AB12C'`.

Comment: I don't think this quite works, because the OP seems to want PS10 and PS20 last, so it's not lexicographic in the number strings.  I think the keyfunc to use is one of the many natural sorts floating around.

Comment: @DSM, this puts PS10 and PS20 last.

Comment: ? I get that the last four terms of `sorted_dict` are `('111111', 'PS10'), ('103661', 'PS2'), ('151515', 'PS20'), ('109754', 'PS3')`, which makes sense, because nothing you've done sorts by integer value.

Comment: Oh, @DSM, yes I see. Though I can't make much sense of the example output as it is, since `'141005'` is (somehow???) first.

Comment: still cannot sort the values basically, what i wanted is the values with alphabets on top. so PSA,PSB,....PSZ, then follwoed by numbers PS1,PS2..PS10,PS11,...PS20. i tried with this option but still the values are sorted alphabets first and numerics later,but the alphabets values itself are not sorted i.e. PSI,PSA,PSC etc

Comment: @user3098561, please example logic more, e.g. what comes first `AB12C` or `AB2C`?

Comment: any suggestions, since i tried and it gives a random sorting for the alphabets and numerics..

Answer (score 1):

I got one way that gives your expected result.

I use `d` for your `dict`, because it is a better identifier.

```
s = sorted([c for c in d.keys() if d[c].isalpha()]) + 
    sorted([c for c in d.keys() if not d[c].isalpha()])
```

Seems this is constructed directly from your defined rules.

This gives `s`:

```
['141005', '151336', '237330', '255695', '265040', '306000', '306762', '309296', '311786', '328371', '329745', '331110', '344331', '367531', '398394', '398436', '398572', '398614', '398920', '399552', '402154', '403714', '403811', '403962', '404370', '404903', '412713', '413635', '420771', '421534', '425822', '425861', '434330', '437653', '439822', '446234', '447616', '451324', '454133', '460145', '460184', '460192', '087265', '103661', '109754', '111111', '151515']
```

Comment: i need the alphabets and numerics also, to be sorted. but they were sorted, it shows the random alphabets and random sorted numerics. but all the alphabets are now on the top and numerics are at the end.

Comment: @user3098561 What do you mean by sort the alphabets and numerics? You want another list represent the values of the `dict`? `dict` itself is unordered, you can only get an sorted list of keys.

Comment: yes ,i wanted is the values with alphabets on top. so PSA,PSB,....PSZ, then followed by numbers PS1,PS2..PS10,PS11,...PS20. so, there should be 2 lists alphabets on top in sorted manner and then followed by numerics that too in sorted order with PS1,PS2..PS10 **not** in order of PS1,PS10,PS2,PS20 etc